# Omnidoc download failure when upgrading play framework from 2.3 to version 2.4

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.4

I'am trying to migrate form play framework version 2.3 to version 2.4, but building failed because of this error:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#play-omnidoc_2.11;2.4.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I tried several versions of omnidoc but the error persist.

Comment: Are you behind any form of proxy on your connection (such as on your company connection)?

Comment: @JonathanMyers, I added this line in the sbt build file, after refresh the build is achieved successfully : ** autoScalaLibrary := false**